# Error while executing 'pip install virtualenv p1'. It installed virtualenv perfectly but It generated error while collecting p1

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

When i executed the above said command in command prompt it generate the following error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (16.7.8)
Collecting p1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/16/a5c2ade5472a8fca3d8ef5cee2214fd49ef827269e85e1c39b7bd6fba56a/p1-1.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting rpi.gpio>=0.5.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/88/d3817eb11fc77a8d9a63abeab8fe303266b1e3b85e2952238f0da43fed4e/RPi.GPIO-0.7.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: rpi.gpio, p1
    Running setup.py install for rpi.gpio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rb458cr0\\rpi.gpio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rb458cr0\\rpi.gpio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-blgtvdr9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rb458cr0\rpi.gpio\
    Complete output (32 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\RPi
    copying RPi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\RPi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\RPi\GPIO
    copying RPi\GPIO\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\RPi\GPIO
    running build_ext
    building 'RPi._GPIO' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\source
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsource/py_gpio.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\source/py_gpio.obj
    py_gpio.c
    source/py_gpio.c(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
    source/py_gpio.c(115): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(119): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(200): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
    source/py_gpio.c(227): warning C4047: 'return': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    source/py_gpio.c(289): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(291): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(345): error C2373: 'output': redefinition; different type modifiers
    C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rb458cr0\rpi.gpio\source\constants.h(29): note: see declaration of 'output'
    source/py_gpio.c(345): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
    source/py_gpio.c(359): warning C4047: 'return': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    source/py_gpio.c(406): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(408): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(410): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(412): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rb458cr0\\rpi.gpio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rb458cr0\\rpi.gpio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-blgtvdr9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am not able to understand it please help. will it create nay problem while creating a project with django. Django installed perfectly everything worked fine. I even verified by opening 'localhost:8000' and it showed it was downloaded perfecty please help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're trying to install package p1, which apparently requires rpi.gpio. As far as I know, this is a Raspberry Pi project and package, I don't think this will compile/install on Windows. Note also that p1 hasn't been changed/maintained since 2015, so wondering why you're using it.

Comment: Why are you installing `virtualenv` at the same time as `p1`? It doesn't make sense. Normally you'd install virtualenv first, then create a virtualenv so you can install packages inside your virtualenv.